# Why doesn't OpenCV's inRange function convert my HSV image to Binary?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to convert the video captured from the camera into binary with thresholds controlled by track bars.

In my code I have converted the RGB video to HSV before using `inRange()` function for thresholding.

When I run my code and change the threshold values nothing happens and I just get the HSV image and not the Binary image.

Can someone tell me how I can fix this?

[image]

```
import serial
import numpy as np
import cv2

# dummy function
def nothing(x):
    pass

# Track bar window
cv2.namedWindow('thresh')

# Track bars
cv2.createTrackbar('lH','thresh', 0, 180, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('uH', 'thresh', 0, 180, nothing)

cv2.createTrackbar('lS', 'thresh', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('uS', 'thresh', 0, 255, nothing)

cv2.createTrackbar('lV', 'thresh', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('uV', 'thresh', 0, 255, nothing)

# capture video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)




while True:
    # Read from camera
    source, frame = cap.read()
    if not source:
        break

    # converting image color to HSV color space
    cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV, frame, 0)

    # Getting values from track bars
    lH = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lH','thresh')
    uH = cv2.getTrackbarPos('uH', 'thresh')
    lS = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lS', 'thresh')
    uS = cv2.getTrackbarPos('uS', 'thresh')
    lV = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lV', 'thresh')
    uV = cv2.getTrackbarPos('uV', 'thresh')

    lowerb = (lH, lS, lV)
    upperb = (uH, uS, uV)
    cv2.inRange(frame, lowerb, upperb, frame)
    cv2.flip(frame, 1, frame)
    cv2.imshow('thresh', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: have you tried: `frame = cv2.inRange(...)` and `frame = cv2.flip(...)` ?

Comment: @Miki I have tried frame = cv2.inRange() but it seems that cv2.inRange() doesn't return anything and all I get is a black image and no matter how much I change the threshold values i still get the black image. Then while trying frame = cv2.inRange(), I did print(frame) and the print result was a matrix filled with zeros.

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting the correct values for lH, uH etc?

Comment: Yeah, I have printed lH, uH  and other similar variables and their values are the same as shown in the track bars. I have even hard coded specific values on a jpg picture but still the inRange function is unable to change the picture to binary.

Comment: try `lowerb = np.array([lH, lS, lV])`, and same for upperb

Comment: tried it and still not working

Comment: I'm sorry but that's all I've got since I cannot try your code right now.. Good luck

Comment: Okay I tried to change lowerb and upperb to this format lowerb = np.array([30, 20, 130], np.uint8) and tried image = inRange(...) on a jpg picture and it worked but when I applied it on the live video I was getting a black image only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution with the help of @Miki in the comments.

Few changes in the code:

```
lowerb = np.array([lH, lS, lV], np.uint8)
upperb = np.array([uH, uS, uV], np.uint8)
```

and also

```
frame = cv2.inRange(frame, lowerb, upperb)
```

The above changes in code fixed the problem.

The complete working code is below

```
import serial
import numpy as np
import cv2

# dummy function
def nothing(x):
    pass

# Track bar window
cv2.namedWindow('thresh')

# Track bars
cv2.createTrackbar('lH','thresh', 0, 180, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('lS', 'thresh', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('lV', 'thresh', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('uH', 'thresh', 0, 180, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('uS', 'thresh', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('uV', 'thresh', 0, 255, nothing)

# capture video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Read from camera
    source, frame = cap.read()
    if not source:
        break

    # converting image color to HSV color space
    cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV, frame, 0)

    # Getting values from track bars
    lH = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lH', 'thresh')
    uH = cv2.getTrackbarPos('uH', 'thresh')
    lS = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lS', 'thresh')
    uS = cv2.getTrackbarPos('uS', 'thresh')
    lV = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lV', 'thresh')
    uV = cv2.getTrackbarPos('uV', 'thresh')

    lowerb = np.array([lH, lS, lV], np.uint8)
    upperb = np.array([uH, uS, uV], np.uint8)

    frame = cv2.inRange(frame, lowerb, upperb)
    cv2.flip(frame, 1, frame)
    cv2.imshow('thresh', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```